# On-demand eager loading

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I make a query:

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a FETCH ALL PROPERTIES " +
        "JOIN a.Bs AS b " +
        "JOIN b.Cs AS c WHERE c = :c";
Query q = DAO.getSession().createQuery(query);
q.setParameter("c", c);
return q.list();
```

Even though I've said `FETCH ALL PROPERTIES` on a, when I access all the collections that A has, they still need to be loaded, thus aren't eagerly loaded. They have been defined as lazy loading, and that is the default behaviour I want, but this is the exception: I would like them loaded right now. I've tried swapping `JOIN` for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to provoke Hibernate into loading them, and I've tried setting `q.setFetchMode("a", FetchMode.EAGER)`, but it doesn't exist for Query.

The list of As is quite long, and they have quite a few collections, so making this an n+1 query thing is very slow (about ten seconds, as opposed to doing it in a single query which would be sub-second speed). I'd far prefer one query and loading all that's necessary in that one go. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

PS, Little bonus question: If I replace the `"JOIN b.Cs AS c WHERE c = :c";`
 line with `"WHERE :c IN b.Cs";`, I get an SQL exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1
```

The double paranthesis it's referring to is "and ('151000000-0000' in (.))" where 151000000-0000 is the primary key of `c`. Any idea why I get this error when I do it this way compared to not getting it when I do it the with joining b.Cs in?

UPDATE, as requested, here is the way I use for mapping. B and C are very similarly designed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblA")
public class A  {
  @Id
  String AId;

  @Column(name = "shortName", length = 12, nullable = false)
  String shortName;

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="theA")
  private Set<B> Bs;

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="theA")
  private Set<D> Ds;

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="theA")
  private Set<E> Es;

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="theA")
  private Set<F> Fs;
}
```

theA in B, D, E and F is defined like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "AId", nullable = true)
@ForeignKey(name="FK_KategoriID")
private A theA;
```

Cheers

Nik

Comment: You would need to post your hibernate mapping files to see how you have disabled lazy loading

Comment: Question updated with sample mapping. I haven't disabled lazy loading at all, everything is lazy loading, but when I do this particular query I want it to eagerly load all properties of A so that I don't get the lazy loading penalty when I loop through the list of As accessing all its properties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fetch all properties` is not what you want; it's used for telling Hibernate that you want it to fetch **single-valued** lazy-loaded properties. Details are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins).

You need to specify `join fetch` in your query instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a
  LEFT JOIN FETCH a.Bs AS b
  LEFT JOIN FETCH b.Cs AS c
 WHERE c = :c
```

As far as bonus question goes, `WHERE :c IN b.Cs` is illegal syntax. Depending on how your `C` is mapped, you may want to look at [`elements()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-expressions) function instead.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't caught that about single-valued lazy loading. Thanks for the tip about LEFT JOIN FETCH :-)

Comment: I know this is old but the links are broken :-)

Comment: @porfiriopartida - links are fixed

Answer (score 1):

`FETCH ALL PROPERTIES` only works for lazy properties (where a property is a String, Integer, ...) not one-to-may associations (i.e. collections)

see A [Short Primer On Fetching Strategies](https://www.hibernate.org/315.html)