# Two way relationship with JsonBackReference & JsonManagedReference

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

**ANSWER**

I'll solve my problem regarding to this blog [Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

Thanks you.

**UPDATE 2**

The problem is about **JsonBackReference** and **JsonManagedReference** annotations.
With my two way relationship, I have to explicitly select one way for serialization with JsonBackReference and JsonManagedReference.
But here, I am in case to use the opposit way "*Parent->Child*" for a specific requierement (using the way "*Child->Parent*" by default)
When I inversed those two annotations, my JSON is what I'm looking for, for the special requierment.
Any idea on how to use JACKSON in a two way relationship ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is a code simple using EntityGraph (thanks to @NeilStockton suggestion), but still don't serialize the lazy attribute in JSON :-(

Parent

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @column
    private String parentAttribute;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", optional = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Child child;
```

Child

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @column
    private String childAttribute;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Parent parent;
```

Parent Repository

```
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "child" })
    //a hack to use findAll with default lazy/eager mapping
    Collection<Parent> findByIdNotNull(); 
}
```

Generated query :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        parent0_.id as id1_33_0_,
        child1_.id as id1_32_1_,
        parent0_.parent_attribute as parent_attribute2_33_0_,
        child1_.child_attribute as child_attribute2_32_1_,
    from
        test.parent parent0_ 
    left outer join
        test.child child1_ 
            on parent0_.id=child1_.parent_id 
    where
        parent0_.id is not null
```

JSON (*no child*):

```
   [ {
    "id": 1
    "parentAttribute": "I am the parent"
    } ]
```

Any idea on how to force Jackson Hibernate4Module to serialize if present ?
Thank you.

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.1 back-office using JPA/hibernate for mapping entities. The front-end is an Angular2 application. The communication is a REST/JSON.
My question is about forcing EAGER loading in some queries when I have a Lazy relationship.
The [solution using JOIN FETCH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668729/6385802) helped me in DAO layer (Repositories). *The entity is now completely loaded in a single query as I want in controllers layer*. **But the serialized JSON still incomplete due to Hibernate4Module**.

Bellow Hibernate4Module features can't help :-(

- FORCE_LAZY_LOADING
- USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION
- SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS
- REQUIRE_EXPLICIT_LAZY_LOADING_MARKER
- REPLACE_PERSISTENT_COLLECTIONS

Any idea is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: JPA 2.1 EntityGraphs allows you to load what you want. Don't see the relevance to JSON to that.

Comment: Thank you @NeilStockton for fast replying. I'm reading JPA 2.1 EntityGraphs doc, and it's verry interrest. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: @NeilStockton, I continue reading about the verry interresting JPA 2.1 EntityGraphs doc. Hibernate4Module check lazy attributes by  HibernateProxy.class.isAssignableFrom. I think the EntityGraph will solve my problem. I'll let you know. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello @NeilStockton. EntityGraph is an elegant way to load what we want lazy/eager. I can see in logs that Hibernate generate one query with left outer join to the lazy attribute. Like with FETCH JOIN, Jackson serialization still the same. The lazy attribute is not present in JSON :-(. Any idea ? Thank you

Comment: @NeilStockton, Hibernate load field when I use FETCH JOIN or EntityGraph. But jackson serialization using Hibernate4Module is not including this field in JSON because of JPA lazy mapping of the field.

Comment: So the problem is not JPA, so remove that from the question. The problem is whatever this "Hibernate4Module" is ... again nothing to do with JPA

Comment: @NeilStockton, ok, thank you for EntityGraph suggestion. The problem is with JsonBackReference and JsonManagedReference

Comment: Finally, I solved my problem by using Custom Projection with a constructor in the select part of a query. In the new projection class, there is no "JsonIgnore" or any JPA annotation that make field not serialized. I added more data in that projection for reach use.

Comment: @Ferhatos can you please provide code same to fix ? i too facing same issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem by using Custom Projection with a constructor in the select part of the query. In the new projection class, there is no "JsonIgnore" or any JPA annotation that make field not serialized by Jackson. I added more data in that projection for reach use.
Hope it'll help.

Comment: Can you please provide the code ? I also having same issue

Comment: @Krish, sorry for long time to response.
You can use a custom query that result in a custom class that is **not annotated as Entity**.

`Class CustomProjection {String name; int Age;}
Query (value = "Select new CustomProject(p.name, Now()-f.birthDay) from person p inner join folder f on f.person_id = p.id")`

Comment: @Ferhatos hey I saw your answer and I have a similair problem, could you look at my question please? I still don't get it . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484788/spring-boot-return-nested-array-however-i-need-to-have-the-data-but-only-onc