# Spring Boot return Nested Array, However... I need to have the data but only once

Tags: java, spring-boot

I think my question is very simple but I have no idea how to solve it.

So I have a **team**, and that **team** can have a **match** ( a match is a battle between 2 teams) . When I get a team, I also want to see the matches he is playing. But I get an inception of matches and teams.

> The matches array has 2 teams, Those teams again have a matches array and so on.

Here is a screenshot to clarify it : [image: Matches array example]
I already tried to put @JsonBackReference above the Set matches variable, but that will just hide the whole array. That is not what I want. I want to show the matches array, and then hide it for "teamHome" as you can see in the picture.

The Controller and Logic class aren't that important for this, so I show you the code of the entities and the relations between them.

The match class :

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="match")
public class Match {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id_home")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"matches"})
    private Team teamHome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id_away")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"matches"})
    private Team teamAway;

    private int scoreTeamHome;

    private int scoreTeamAway;

    private int nrOfWinsNeeded;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private Date date;

    public Match() {
    }

    public Match(Team teamHome, Team teamAway, int scoreTeamHome, int scoreTeamAway, int nrOfWinsNeeded, Date date){
        this.teamHome = teamHome;
        this.teamAway = teamAway;
        this.scoreTeamHome = scoreTeamHome;
        this.scoreTeamAway = scoreTeamAway;
        this.nrOfWinsNeeded = nrOfWinsNeeded;
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

The teams class:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "`team`")
public class Team {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String country;

   @Column(nullable = false, name = "code_name")
   private String codeName;

   @JsonBackReference
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "team_id") // we need to duplicate the physical information
   private Set<Match> matches;


//    @OneToMany
//    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id") // we need to duplicate the physical information
//    private Set<Player> players;

//  Make sure the player array is not shown in the team
   @JsonBackReference
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
   private Set<Player> players;

   public Team(){

   }


   public Team(String name, String country, String codeName) {
       this.name = name;
       this.country = country;
       this.codeName = codeName;
   }


}
```

**EDIT - I FIXED IT**
I added
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"matches"}) above teamHome and teamAway. This prevents that it returns the matches array in the child object.

I edited the code.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268465/two-way-relationship-with-jsonbackreference-jsonmanagedreference

Comment: @Taschi Thanks,I am not sure but I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Taschi I fixed it. I searched some more and just added the follow :     @JsonIgnoreProperties({"matches"}) :)

Comment: Yeah, that's also a way to circumvent this problem.

Comment: @Taschi yess :)